# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Tags: asp.net, api, web

I am a new bee to web services and I have to publish a web service to a server.

I added an application using IIS but when I try to browse the application it gives me this error.

**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I had seen other answers about this issue,where most of them are related to installing Microsoft.AI.Web package. This is already installed in my web service and I am still getting the error.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: You say that you installed Microsoft.AI.Web to your server. So, that means the required DLLs are probably in the GAC and not in your /bin folder. Is that correct?

Comment: Microsoft.AI.Web assembly is already installed in my web api through NuGet Package Manager before deploying it to IIS on server.

Answer (score 1):

There was an update waiting on the Nuget package manager for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, after updating it added the application again to IIS. This resolved my error.

Comment: This was actually what helped me also. Let me clarify. In Solution Explorer, right-click the Web Api Project. Go to Application Insights > Configure Application Inisights. Now you will see a new tab. Inside this one there was the update message. It updated from 2.0.0 to 2.4.0. Using aso.net 4.7.1 Now this is gone but now I have to deal with `Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation` not found.